# how to force any application into fullscreen?

Tags: windows, fullscreen

I couldn't find any solution to this, even though it should be the most obvious and easy thing to do.

I basically just want to be able to force any program that can be switched to fullscreen with alt+enter to automatically run in fullscreen.

I tried to change a shortcut to run "maximized", but that's not fullscreen. I tried to write -fullscreen and /fullscreen after the Target of the shortcut, but it didnt work, and I also think its program specific.

I tried using programs like ShiftWindow, but they can only do borderless windowed mode.

The programs I try to run in fullscreen use directx, if that means anything.

I also tried programname.exe /?, programname.exe /help, programname.exe -help, programname.exe --help and programname.exe -? in the command line to see the possible commands it would accept in the target field, but it did nothing when it wasn't in the directory set in the command line, and only opened the program when it was there.

Are there no alternatives to alt+enter? it really cant be set automatically in windows or anywhere?

Comment: Sometimes I have good luck trying a keyboard shortcut from one program in a different program.  In that spirit, please try F11.

Comment: doesnt work, and i believe it would still need to be pressed every time if it did